# getscript doesnt work after clearing cache

Tags: jquery, getscript

I am using getscript() to load some scripts for my image gallery. As soon as I click on the gallery, this code runs :

```
$(function () {
$(window).hashchange(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#nav li a').click(function () {
            $('#content-wrap').load(toLoad, showNewContent);

            function showNewContent() {
                if ($('#content-wrap').is(':empty')) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    if (window.location.hash == "#photos") {
                        alert("soundswaste1");
                        $.getScript("galleria/galleria-1.2.8.min.js");
                        $.getScript("galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js", getGalleria);

                        function getGalleria() {
                            alert("soundswaste2");
                            $.getScript("galleria.js");
                        }
                    }
                    $('#content-wrap').fadeIn(500).css("display", "block");
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

First I go to chrome console -> right click on network tab -> clear browser cache -> refresh the page -> and click on photos.
I get alert "soundswaste1" and the effect doesn't run. The images just line up on the page.

Then I simply click on 'photos' again, and I get both the alerts, each of them **twice**.
2 questions :

1. Why does clearing-cache prevents all the scripts from loading the first time. Is it because they are located at different paths?
2. Why do I get the alerts **twice** the 2nd time?

Comment: why would `$(window).hashchange` run before `$(document).ready`, why would `$(window).hashchange` be run if you navigated away from a page and reloaded the script?
why do you have `$(function () {` and `$(document).ready` ? all in all, remove your first two lines of code and the two lines of code. everything should be ok after that.

Comment: Ok I removed the first 2 and last 2 lines, and its just document.ready now. I am not getting the alerts twice anymore, but issue#1 still remains. If I clear the cache, it doesn't work the first time. It works only when I click on the link again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess `galleria.classic.min.js` depends on `galleria-1.2.8.js`
on first load, you tried loading both of them one after the other,
but that dosent make sure that when the second scripts is loaded the first is done loading.
so on the `success` of the first, load the second, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nav li a').click(function () {
        $('#content-wrap').load(toLoad, showNewContent);

        function showNewContent() {
            if ($('#content-wrap').is(':empty')) {
                return false;
            } else {
                if (window.location.hash == "#photos") {
                    alert("soundswaste1");
                    $.getScript("galleria/galleria-1.2.8.min.js",

                    function () {
                        $.getScript("galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js",

                        function () {
                            alert("soundswaste2");
                            $.getScript("galleria.js");
                        });
                    });


                }
                $('#content-wrap').fadeIn(500).css("display", "block");
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```